# Easiest way to get a specific section of a file path

Tags: python, parsing, filepath, fileparsing, fileparse

I have a bit of a tricky one to solve.  I have the need to extract a specific portion of a file path.  I've extracted a zip file under a temp directory have have the full path to the file.  Essentially what I would like is to get the difference between the full file path and the temp path.  Let me give an example below:

```
Fullpath = c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\common\\test.txt

TempPath = c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\
```

So my expected results would be to have the following:

```
results = \\common\\test.txt
```

Just looking for an easy, Pythonic way to accomplish this.

Comment: Keep in mind, this subdirectory path under the temporary directory can change.  It could be 1 or many levels deep to the file.

Comment: A robust solution would resolve different absolute paths resolving to the same working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [os.path.relpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath):

```
os.path.relpath(Fullpath, TempPath)
```

Or you can use split:

```
Fullpath.split(TempPath)[1]
```

Or you can use commonprefix with replace as:

```
Fullpath.replace(os.path.commonprefix([Fullpath, TempPath]),'')
```

Output:

```
common\test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I like the usage of 'os.path.relpath(Fullpath, TempPath)'.  I guess the remaining question I have is how would one strip the file name off and leave the directory.  so for example, the results would be common\ instead of common\test.txt

Answer (score 0):

A less than fully robust way is to use [os.path.commonprefix](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix):

```
import os

Fullpath = 'c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\common\\test.txt'
TempPath = 'c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\'

print os.path.commonprefix([Fullpath, TempPath])
# c:\users\test\appdata\local\temp\tempDir\
```

Be aware thought that the function does not know anything about paths; it is [just a character by character deal](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2002-December/030947.html).

Then use str.partition to get the part you are interested in:

```
>>> print Fullpath.partition(os.path.commonprefix([Fullpath, TempPath]))
('', 'c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\', 'common\\test.txt')
```

If you have a situation like so:

```
Fullpath = 'c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\common\\test.txt'
TempPath = 'c:\\users\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\co'
```

It is better to wrap the common prefix with os.path.dirname

```
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.commonprefix([Fullpath, TempPath]))
c:\users\test\appdata\local\temp\tempDir\
```

But that still does not fix a situation like this:

```
Fullpath = 'c:\\users\\test\\..\\test\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tempDir\\common\\test.txt'
```

Where you need to resolve full absolute path names before parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = '\\' + Fullpath.replace(TempPath, '')
```

Or if you want to be sure to remove the beginning of the string:

```
import re
results = '\\' + re.sub('^%s' % TempPath, '', Fullpath)
```